# Finding Inverse function

Tags: inverse-function

$$x^3+8x+3=y$$
How am I suppose to make $y$ the subject? I'm not sure how to find its inverse, for example how to I find $f^{-1}(12)$

Comment: $$1^3+8\times 1+3 = 12$$

Comment: if $x=1$ then $y=12$ There is a formula for the inverse function using Cardano's method, but it is intricate

Comment: The only way to find a general $f^{-1}(y)$ is to use the cubic formula, which is messy. For particular values of $y,$ however, you might just find the $x$ by trial and error.  https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/

Answer (score 0):

Consistent with Will Jagy's comment, since
$\displaystyle (4 \times 8^3)
+ (27 \times 3^2) > 0,$ 
you are guaranteed that the equation only has 1 real root, which may be computed as shown by [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula).

Also, if
$\displaystyle f(x)=x^3 + 8x + 3$,
then $\displaystyle f′(x)=3x^2 + 8.$

This means that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

This means that $f(x)$ is injective, which implies that there is a general function $g(y)$ such that $f(x) = y \iff g(y)=x.$

Therefore, the general inverse function that you speak of does exist.

---

The general function $g(y)$ may be analytically constructed as follows:

- Make $y$ a **variable** in $\Bbb{R}.$
- Construct $f_y(x)=(x^3 +8x + 3) − y.$
- Then, $f_y(x) = 0 \iff f(x) = y.$

Therefore, following the link in in the first paragraph of my answer, simply apply Cardano's formula to $f_y(x)$ to obtain the value of $x,$ in terms of $y$. This construction, is in effect a function $g(y)$ such that $g(y)=x.$

---

Notice that with $f(x)$ strictly increasing and injective, $f_y(x)$ is simply $f(x)$ plus a constant.  This means that the behavior of $f_y(x)$ will parallel $f(x)$, and so $f_y(x)$ will also only have 1 real root.